# Fill Shapes in OpenGL using C++

Tags: opengl, visual-c++

How I can fill shape as rectangle in OpenGL using C++ with any color but **without change the color it s border** (border is the lines from which the rectangle is formed)?

Since when I used `glBegin(GL_POLYGON)` function to fill the rectangle, the border is also filled but I do not want to change the color of border.

#### The code which I used is below:

```
 void display( )
   {
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
      glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
         glVertex2i(50,90);
         glVertex2i(100,90);
         glVertex2i(100,150);
         glVertex2i(50,150);
      glEnd();
      glFlush();       

    }
```

Comment: How are you drawing the border?

Comment: I mean the lines from which the rectangle is formed

Answer (score 2):

```
void display( )
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Draw the Polygon First
  glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
     glVertex2i(50,90);
     glVertex2i(100,90);
     glVertex2i(100,150);
     glVertex2i(50,150);
  glEnd();

  // Draw the border next
  glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
     glVertex2i(50,90);
     glVertex2i(100,90);
     glVertex2i(100,150);
     glVertex2i(50,150);
  glEnd();
  glFlush();       

}
```